# What is the recommended way to use an encapsulated directive and routing within an AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to adopt **best practices with an AngularJs 1.5 app**. Already following [Todd Motto's](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide) and [John Papa's](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) style guides

The thing is: my app has **routes using ngRoute**. So, this:

```
function RoutingConfig($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/route1', {
            controller: 'Ctrl1 as vm',
            templateUrl: 'partials/route1.html',
            resolve: { myCoolService: myCoolService } // to abbreviate
        })
        .when('/route2', {
            controller: 'Ctrl2 as vm',
            templateUrl: 'partials/route2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/route1'}):

}

angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(RoutingConfig);
```

Ok. So far, so good.

Now, let's say that, in my road to Angular 2, **I want to adopt the *encapsulate everything in a directive* approach**. This way, I'll create something like **web components, using AngularJS 1.5**.

If I'm following the right practices, I could create a directive for my route1 and directly define a controller for that directive:

```
function MyCoolDirective() {
    var directiveDefObj = {
        controller: Ctrl1,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        scope: {
            data: "=",
        },
        bindToController: true, // isolated scope
        link: linkFnc // just declared to abbreviate
    };

    return directiveDefObj;
}


angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('MyCoolDirective', MyCoolDirective);
```

So, **where should I declare the Controllers? In the routing configuration? Inside each directive?** Sounds a bit redundandt for me.

Comment: there are indeed two separate controllers here; one for the route and everything in it's template, the other for the directive and everything in it's template.  However, if your intent is for the route template to only hold directives and do no logic on it's own, it isn't necessary to provide a controller.  In practice, however, you will likely need both, especially if you plan to have multiple directives which share information between each other.

Comment: You don't really need route controllers anymore. You can just make the template for your route a directive and put all your controller logic in the directive. e.g. `.when('/route1', {template: '<my-cool-directive></my-cool-directive>'})`

Comment: Yes, that's my idea: move the complexity to directives, and doesn't have routing controllers, if possible. To handle the communication between directives (typical example of outer directive for a container and inner directive for each of the contained elements), couldn't I just use 'require' in my inner directives?

Comment: That's right, the only thing that route controller is necessary for is injecting route resolvers and binding them to view scope. Views don't have access to resolvers, but controllers do.

Comment: angular 1.5 introduced components to streamline directives in preparation for angular 2 https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, this is how I handle controllers in directives ala the papa style guide

As mentioned above I recommend checking out the new angular 1.5 component method in preparations for angular 2. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('AppName')
        .directive('directiveName', directiveName)
        .config(routeConfig);

    directiveName.$inject = ['$compile'];

    function directiveName($compile) {
        return {
            scope: {
                customAttribute: '=',
            },
            link: directiveLink,
            controller: directiveController
        };

        function directiveLink(scope) {

        }

        function directiveController($scope) {

        }
    }
    routeConfig.$inject ['$routeProvider'];

    function routeConfig($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/home', {
            template: '<custom-directive></custom-directive>',
            resolve: {
                user: function($http) { return $http.get('...'); }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty clean. I actually use 'component' instead of 'directive' sometimes, but I'm preparing material for an AngularJS class, and wanted to show the evolution, to understand the use of 'component', and why we got there.

Comment: Just another question: you injected $compile into the directive. What would you use it for? If I'm not wrong, you can use it to change the DOM of the directive prior to its instantiation, unlike the link function. Is there any clear use case for that?

Comment: Use compile to allow angular to 'do its thing'. More specifically, compile is what angular uses to render templates. Compile allows you to create new scopes and bind them to templates on the fly. Consider the following: https://gist.github.com/d3l33t/87adc735266077c2af3840e1a115c1c4

I can use compile to create new elements on the page that has two way data binding to the parent scope. I can create functions on the parent scope and allow child directives to operate independently.

Comment: word of caution: compile only needs to happen once angular will handle change detection on the scope for you.

Comment: Oh, I get it. That's pretty powerful. Thanks!